# python requests cannot download a zip file while browser/selenium can

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I tried to use requests module to download a bunch of zip files with the code below:

```
s = requests.Session()
url='http://data.theice.com/MyAccount/Login.aspx'
z=s.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(z.content,'html.parser')
hidden=soup.find_all('input',attrs={'type':'hidden'})
values={'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LoginControl$m_userName':'Acorn437',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LoginControl$m_password':'*******',
    '__EVENTTARGET':'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LoginControl$LoginButton',
    '__EVENTARGUMENT':'',
    '__LASTFOCUS':''}
values=dict(values,**{i['id']:i['value'] for i in hidden})
z=s.post(url,data=values,allow_redirects=True)
```

After here, I verified that I have successfully loginned into the website by checking the response. Now I would like to download the zip file from a link on the website

```
link='http://data.theice.com/MyAccount/Download.aspx?PUID=69590&PDS=0&PRODID=580&TS=2018'
resp=s.get(link,allow_redirects=True)   
path=os.getcwd()+'\\data\\ice_zip\\'
fname='test.zip'
zfile=open(path+fname,'wb')
zfile.write(resp.content)
zfile.close()
```

However, it turned out that what I downloaded is acutally a html file intead of the zip file I need. I have no idea why the requests module does not work for this website. I think after I login in with requests.session, I should be able to download it because I can do it with a browser or the selenium module.

Clearly, I have no problem logining into the

Comment: There are many reasons this could differ: cookies, referer, user-agent, accept headers, custom extra headers, … Some of these things could be set by JavaScript on the page, others just by the browser being a browser. The only way to know what's relevant is to capture the outgoing request from the browser, compare it to the request from requests, and start changing things that are different until you figure out which one matters.

Comment: Have you tested out if the login was successful?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me - given of course you provide your own credentials and download path... I think your main problem might be that your login URL was wrong. When I ran your code I could NOT login to the site. The intial URL and the login URL are different ones.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# define variables
username = ""
password = ""
path_to_store_output = ""

session = requests.Session()
r = session.get('http://data.theice.com/MyAccount/Login.aspx'')
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')

vs_generator = soup.find('input', attrs={'id': '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'}).get('value')
vs = soup.find('input', attrs={'id': '__VIEWSTATE'}).get('value')
event_validation = soup.find('input', attrs={'id': '__EVENTVALIDATION'}).get('value')


payload = {
    "__EVENTTARGET": "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LoginControl$LoginButton",
    "__EVENTARGUMENT":"", 
    "__LASTFOCUS": "", 
    "__VIEWSTATE": vs,
    "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR": vs_generator,
    "__EVENTVALIDATION": event_validation,
    "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LoginControl$m_userName": username,
    "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LoginControl$m_password": password  
}
# doing a POST to login
r = session.post("http://www.ice.if5.com/MyAccount/Login.aspx", data=payload, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36'})

# check if we're logged in
if not username in r.text:
    print("[!] Bommer, dude! We're not logged in...")

else:
    print("[*] Score, we're in. Let's download stuff...")
    r = session.get("http://www.ice.if5.com/MyAccount/Download.aspx?PUID=70116&PDS=2&PRODID=4133", headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36'})
    with open(path_to_store_output, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)
```

There's actually not much to this. Login and grab the stuff. Replace the url, I tested with whatever you're interested in. The one you provided gave me a 404. Cheers.